# Trying to figure out website failure rate and last date of failure with PowerShell on CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, automation

I want to be able to calculate the success rate for website logins based off of information contained in a .CSV document. The problem that I am having is that I would like to get results for each website individually. Right now I can only get results for all three of the websites as a whole. Would I be able to get some help on this? Thanks again!

The .CSV file has  the following information.

```
A Date Column with a Timestamp,  
A Status Column that says Success or Failure, and  
A column that has the websites.
```

Reading stack overflow and other PowerShell Resources

```
$sites = "Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3"

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    # Total count of websites
    $total = $site.Column3.Count

    #Looking for websites that where sucessful based off of sucess in second column
    $Sucess = $total | Where-Object { $PSItem.Status -like "*Sucess*" } 

    # Calculating the percent of websites 
    $percent = [math]::Round($failed.Count / $total.count * 100, 1)

    #Going through CSV File to figure out last date of failure for wach website
    $date = $failed | Select date -Last 1 | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
    Write-Host ("{0} failed {1} % of the time on {2}" -f $site, $percent, $date)



I am trying to create a script with the following output as a .csv file: 
•   Website 1 was successfully able to connect %xx of the time the last failure date is (Date Goes here)
•   Website 2 was successfully able to connect %xx of the time the last failure date is (Date Goes here)  
•   Website 3 was successfully able to connect %xx of the time the last failure date is (Date Goes here)  

it now say: 
Website 1 Succeeded  0 % of the time on 
Website 2 Succeeded 0 % of the time on 
Website 3  Succeeded 0 % of the time on


A sample of the data looks like this: 
date                    status    website
Friday 08/02/2019 13:15 Success Website 1
Friday 08/02/2019 13:15 Failed  Website 2
Friday 08/02/2019 13:15 Success Website 3
Friday 08/02/2019 13:21 Success Website 1
```

Comment: You definitely don't need `Write-Host` here. I'd remove that.

Comment: [1] your comment about the output is ... very peculiar. that is NOT a CSV file - it's just a text file. [*grin*] ///// [2] please add the sample input data to your Original Post so that folks can see why your code is written the way it is ... and how to improve or fix it.

Comment: `$PSItem.Status -like "*Sucess*"` has a misspelling of Success. So that will result in 0 matches if the CSV has the correct spelling. `$total` is only counting what is in one field for one row because you are using `$site.Column3.count`. If that column does not contain a collection, then you probably meant for that to be `$total = $sites.Column3.Count` and therefore it does not need to be in the loop. There is also a variable `$failed` that is not defined in the sample.

Comment: ATM your foreach iterates a static array which can't have any properties, so where should the data come from?

Comment: This is a sample of my table data. I do not know to format the table correctly

Comment: I have put it in the post of the question

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you are calling the **$failed.Count** without defining the **$failed** variable.

```
$percent = [math]::Round($failed.Count / $total.count * 100, 1)
```